# Proof that the category of presheaves on a category $C$ is equivalent to the category of presheaves on its Karoubi envelope

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $C$ be category, let $PSh(C) = [C^{op},$ **Set**$]$ be the category of presheaves on $C$, the Karoubi envelope of $C$, denoted $\overline{C}$, is defined as the full subcategory of $PSh(C)$ which are retracts of objects in $C$ under the Yoneda embedding.

I'm reading this paper on Karoubi envelopes ("Cauchy completion in category theory" by Borceux and Dejean), on page 3 (theorem 1) they say:

**"(4) The category $PSh(\overline{C})$ of presheaves on $\overline{C}$
is equivalent to the category $PSh(C)$ of presheaves on $C$"**

I'm interested to see how they proved this equivalence so I've been trying to follow the whole proof to get to where they prove it but frankly I'm stuck and a lot of what they're saying is going over my head, like for example this:

**"If every idempotent of $C$ splits, every retract of a representable
functor $C(-,c)$ induces an idempotent on $C(-,c)$, thus an idempotent
$e$ on $C$, $e$ splits in $C$, which produces a retraction of $c$ and
thus a retraction of $C(-,c)$, which..."**

That's where I first got lost, every retract of a representable functor induces an idempotent on itself thus an idempotent $e$ on $C$ that splits?? Don't follow at all, I tried to skip to the next paragraph (where they prove the equivalence), it says:

**"To prove (4), it suffices to show that every presheaf $F$ on $C$ can
be uniquely (up to an isomorphism) extended in a presheaf
$\overline{F}$ on $\overline{C}$."**

("extended IN a presheaf $\overline{F}$"? I guess they mean "extended TO a presheaf $\overline{F}$" right?), then they write:

**"From the uniqueness of the splitting in $\overline{C}$ of an
idempotent $e \in C$ and the Cauchy completeness of the category of sets (Proposition 1), $\overline{F}$ has to map the splitting of $e$ on the splitting of $F e$."**

(Don't they mean $\overline{F}$ has to map the splitting of $e$ TO the splitting of $F(e)$? What do they mean by ON?)

The proof is longer but I just about stopped there, couldn't follow the rest of the proof, can anyone provide some clarification on this?

Please be nice to me :)

Comment: You shouldn't have skipped ahead. The bit about idempotents is very important! The key point is that the Yoneda embedding is fully faithful, so any idempotent on $\mathcal{C}(-, c)$ comes from a unique idempotent on $C$, and that the splitting of an idempotent is preserved by any functor whatsoever.

Comment: Try reading this paper http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.rmjm/1250130302, which is one of the original references on the subject. The terminology is a bit outdated but the paper is very readable.

Comment: what paper is it ? link seems broken